# How do I set highcharts line graph point colors to an array of colors?

Tags: highcharts

I've spent some time poking around the API documentation, and I don't see a simple solution to my problem. This is what I'm looking for:

In a chart, I can set each line to be a different color I choose like

```
colors: [ 'red', 'green', 'blue ]
```

But what if I want the points to be different colors than the line?

I know I can set the

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            marker: {
                fillColor: 'yellow',
                lineColor: 'yellow' 
            }
        }
    },
```

But what if I want each point marker to be a different color? (For instance, I want the blue line to have dark blue points, the red line the have dark red points, and the green line to have dark green points.

I think I want to do something along the lines of

```
borderColors: [ 'darkBlue', 'darkGreen', 'darkRed' ]
```

or whatever and the same with fillColors...

Is there any way I can do this easily that I've missed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Define the marker in the series...

I found this in the api:[Highchart symbol api](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.marker.symbol)

Which links to this fiddle:
[High char jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-marker-symbol/)

changed the code to work with colour:

```
$(function () {
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 316.4, 294.1, 195.6, 154.4],
        marker: {
                fillColor: '#f11',
                lineWidth: 2,
                lineColor: '999'
        }
    }, {
        data: [216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5],
        marker: {
                fillColor: '#999',
                lineWidth: 2,
                lineColor: '#111' 
        }
    }]
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a way to do it without manually adding a line and fill color to each series.

Comment: colour is the only to level setting, other ones have to be set in the series or plot options. I have not used it but they apparently have a template option...

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the line color and the marker color for each series explicitly.

[**`Series Color`**](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data.color) Sets the color to the series.

[**`Markers Color`**](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data.marker.fillColor) sets the color to every point in the series.

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gopinaghr/GfjmL/2/) .